# Get text after string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for help to create a regular expression that can get a certain text after a given string using Python.

I'm trying to extract a JSON from a page and it's like this:

```
    var config = {aslkdjsakljdkalsj{asdasdas}askldjaskljd};
```

I need a regex that can get from the first { to the } => without the semicolon

I've tried using

```
    config = .*?(?=\}\;)
```

but the output is

```
    config = {sadasdasdas{a}asdasdasd
```

It gets the `config =` part and doesn't get the last `}`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What language are you implementing this in?

Comment: Also, `{aslkdjsakljdkalsj{asdasdas}askldjaskljd};` is not JSON

Comment: I'm not implementing yet. I'm trying to find the right pattern using [link](https://regexr.com/).

Comment: And yes, in this example it's not a JSON.

Comment: Which language you're using *really matters* - in some languages, this is impossible, in others, it's doable.

Comment: Ok, i'm thinking about doing it in python or ruby. Maybe c#.

Comment: Unless you specify *one*, any potential answers will simply be *guessing*

Comment: It's going to be python.

Comment: I came up with a pattern that works for parsing JSON, but are you sure that `config` is actually in JSON format (rather than being an object)? They're very different

Comment: It's a JSON. {"Acabei": "hahsj", "223": "234"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your line of JS there is *guaranteed* to contain no newline characters before the terminating `;`, then the problem is simple enough - match `var config =`, followed by non-newline characters captured in a group, and then matcha semicolon and the end of the line. If the JSON is delimited with `'`s, then, for example, use the pattern

```
var config = '(.+)';$
```

and extract the first group.

```
input = '''
  var config = '{ "foo": "b\\ar", "ba{{}}}{{z": ["buzz}", "qux", {"innerprop": "innerval"}]}';
  var someOtherVar = 'bar';
'''
match = re.search("(?m)var config = '(.+)';$", input);
```

If the JSON *isn't* guaranteed to be on its own line, then it's a lot more complicated. Parsing nested structures like JSON is difficult - the only way the general problem is solvable with regular expressions is if the structure is known beforehand (which often isn't the case, and can require a lot of repetitive code in the pattern), or if the RE engine being used supports recursive matches. Without that, there's no way to to express the need for a *balanced* number of `{`s with `}`s in the pattern.

Luckily, if you're working with Python, even though Python's native REs don't support recursion, there'a a [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) available that does. You'll also need to make sure that the `{` and `}`s that may come *inside* of strings in the JSON don't affect the current nesting level. For a raw string, you'd need a pattern like

```
var config = String\.raw`\K({(?:"(?:\\|\\"|[^"])*"|[^{}]|(?1))*})(?=`;)
```

The outside of the capture group is

```
var config = String\.raw`\K({ ... })(?=`;)
```

matching the line you want and the string delimiters, with a capturing group of

```
{(?:"(?:\\|\\"|[^"])*"|[^{}]|(?1))*}
```

which means - `{`, followed by any number of: either

- `"(?:\\|\\"|[^"])*"` - match a string inside the JSON (either a key or a value), from its starting delimiter to its ending delimiter, ignoring escaped `"`s, or
- `[^{}]` - Match anything that isn't a `{` or `}` - other characters can be ignored, since we just want to get the nesting level right, or
- `(?1)` - Recurse the whole first capture group (the one that matches the `{ ... }`)

This will ensure that the `{` `}` brackets are balanced by the end of the pattern.

---

But - the above is an example where `String.raw` was used, where literal backslashes in the Javascript code indicate literal backslashes in the string. With `'` delimiters, on the other hand, literal backslashes need to be *double*-escaped in the JS, so the above input would look like

```
var config = '{ "foo": "b\\\\ar", "ba{{}}}{{z": ["buzz}", "qux", {"innerprop": "innerval"}]}';
```

requiring double-escaping the backslashes in the pattern as well:

```
var config = '\K({(?:"(?:\\\\|\\\\"|[^"])*"|[^{}]|(?1))*})(?=';)
```

https://regex101.com/r/8rSrGf/1

It's pretty complicated. I'd recommend going with the first approach or a variation on it instead, if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for the editing and answer. Really helped me.